# Creating custom Django Rest Framework permision

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-permissions

I have created a django rest custom  permision and for testing purposes I made sure `has_object_permission` and `has_permission` retrun `False`.

```
from rest_framework import permissions


class IsWorker(permissions.BasePermission):
    message = "Login with Supplier Account"
    
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        return False
        
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return False
```

How comes this view doesn't work as expected?

```
from packages.models import Package
from .serializers import WorkerPackageSerializer
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from api.permissions import IsWorker

class WorkerPackageDetailViewSet(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):

    serializer_class = WorkerPackageSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, IsWorker)
    lookup_field = "id"

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Package.objects.all()
```

**Expectations:**
I thought it would return a `forbidden` error with the message `Login with Supplier Account` but if the user is not authenticated it returns a not authenticated error and if the user is authenticated it returns the data without any error.

Comment: I figured out the issue was with my URLs. otherwise, everything works fine. I called wrong views in my routes